# Facebook not showing correct image when sharing from page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-networking

When I pass an image URL to Facebook for someone to post to their page (i.e.: www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?), it doesn't pull the correct image using the picture= variable.  I assign it http://cbcoupons.com/imagegen.php?type=CouponSaved&coupon=192 but it drops the &coupon=192.

An example URL for the Facebook share would be:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=162054587279357&link=http://cbcoupons.com/249/0/Restaurants+/Puerto+Vallarta&picture=http://cbcoupons.com/imagegen.php?type=CouponSaved&coupon=192&name=Chicken%20Fajita%20Deal!&caption=Puerto%20Vallarta&description=Chicken%20Fajita%20Deal!%20-%201/2%20Price%20Chicken%20Fajita%20when%20you%20buy%201%20at%20regular%20price%20&redirect_uri=http://cbcoupons.com/

The image that is posted is cbcoupons.com/imagegen.php?type=CouponSaved.

How can get the &coupon=(whatever #) to actually be used?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to URL encode your string so it can accept the '&' character. Otherwise, the Facebook feed API will see it as another parameter. Try:
http://cbcoupons.com/imagegen.php?type=CouponSaved%26coupon=192